# How to remove USB dependency form the boot process?

Tags: linux, centos-5

I have just installed the centos 5.3 on my server machine. It looks for a USB media to boot. But I am not able to figure it out what i have done wrong. Why does it asks for USB media?

If I have created a dependency of USB to boot, Is there any way i can remove this dependency. Or I have to reinstall the OS again?

Regards,
Vijay Shanker Dubey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of boot devices is in system BIOS. You should check first that it has the right HDD listed as the first boot device. It should, however, try to boot from other disks than USB, if so configured. This way you can leave the USB as an "overriding" boot disk, if necessary - and have a bootable USB medium.

The other place where this depedency can be, is the boot loader (e.g. GRUB or Lilo). So, make sure that the boot loader is accessing the right disk as well. On a typical install the system should boot from first HDD, hd(0, 0) in GRUB.